# Selenium C# - How to verify dropdown list

Tags: c#, list, selenium, drop-down-menu

I need to verify drop down values using Selenium in C#. I have a set of values I want to test against with a IWebElements IList of this:

```
        IList<IWebElement> yearsDropdown = { "Select...", "Before 1996", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", "2000" }
```

I need to write a function that return all the values from a drop down (that has the same exact information) and then do an assert to confirm the match. Below is the code that i have written to print the values from drop down, but i need to assert those values with expected ones:

```
       IList<IWebElement> yearsDropdown = { "Select...", "Before 1996", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016" };
        string[] dropdownListArray = new string[23];
        IList<IWebElement> dropdownList = wd.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#Components_0__Entity_SourceInfo_Value_Entity_ModelYear"));
        foreach(IWebElement i in dropdownList)
        {
            dropdownListArray[] = i.Text;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < dropdownList.Count; i++)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(yearsDropdown[i], dropdownList[i].Text);
        }
```

The thing is, when I tried this, it brought back the entire dropdown from the IWebElement IList dropdownList.  I need to have that IWebElement list to be broken down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{ "Select...", "Before 1996", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", "2000" }` is list of string, not IWebElement. 
 See code below:

```
List<string> yearsDropdown = new List<string>(){ "Select...", "Before 1996", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016" };
IList<IWebElement> dropdownList = wd.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#Components_0__Entity_SourceInfo_Value_Entity_ModelYear"));
foreach(IWebElement i in dropdownList)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(i.Text, yearsDropdown.Text);
}
```

Comment: I kept getting this error: "Array initializers can only be used in a variable or field initializer. Try using a new expression instead."

So I took a roundabout way of solving it and just turning yearsDropdown into one string and it worked.  To make sure it works in the future when more years are added, I'll make an if statement that will update the variable to always have the correct years.

Comment: @Tscott Sorry for my mistake, the first line should be `List<string> yearsDropdown = new List<string>(){ "Select...", "Before 1996", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016" };`. I've already updated my answer.